# Getting Rid of the WordPress.com Toolbar on Other Sites?

Tags: admin, wordpress.com-hosting

I recently started a WordPress blog, and now I get an ajax-loaded toolbar showing up at the top of tonnes of pages.  It's all links to my WordPress accounts and blogs and stuff.  It's fine that it shows up when I'm on WordPress or working with my blog, but I see it now on all sites that (I'm presuming) are built on WordPress.com).  i.e. [failblog.org](http://www.failblog.org).

Is there any way to turn off this toolbar?

[image: Screenshot of WordPress.com Toolbar]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your user stylesheet:

```
#wpcombar
{
    height:         2px     !important;
    overflow:       hidden  !important;
}
#wpcombar:hover,
#wpcombar:focus
{
    height:         28px    !important;
}
```

This will shrink down the toolbar to a 2px line. You may use `display:none` to remove it completely, but then it will not be accessible when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to turn off that admin bar.

Sites like "failblog.org" are actually wordpress.com blogs, so the bar will show up everytime you are logged in to your wordpress.com blog.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (2) ways to get rid of the toolbar that I can think of:

1. **Logout of WordPress.com** when you are on one of these sites:

   [image: How to logout of WordPress.com while on Failblog]
   <sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101023-211037.png))</sub>
2. If you find logging out of your WordPress blog is inconvenient you can get yourself a [**self-hosted WordPress blog**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/self-hosted-wordpress-org-vs-free-wordpress-com-infograph/) and then, once you logout from your WordPress.com account this problem will go away. *(I like to recommend [A Small Orange](http://www.asmallorange.com/hosting/shared/) for users moving from WordPress.com to self-hosted because at $25/year they've got the least expensive hosting on a quality webhost I know of, and they are also my current webhost. And just to be explicit, no it is not an affiliate link. :)*